# Reset() and class="btn garlic-auto-save" type="reset" not actually reseting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

This is more like an open-ended one. I have both:

```
<input class="btn garlic-auto-save" type="reset" value="clear" style="align:right"/>
```

and

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('f1').reset()" value="clear" style="align:right"/>
```

Now, by default both of them work, but unfortunately none of them seems to clear one particular page. When I click the buttons they clear the form but the selection on radio and check boxes still remains. Funny thing is that on another page even the `reset()` works. For local storage I am using garlic but even so when is a `reset()` is called the data must be reset at least for the current session. And idea what might be causing the bug ? If you need more info I'll be here. Thanks

Comment: Worked with garlic. Pretty buggy thing.

Comment: reset usually restores a form to the state it was in when the page was loaded. If it was empty, it should make it empty. If you prepopulated anything, it will reset it to the prepopulated state. Just wanted to make sure that isn't your issue?

Comment: Ahh actually that might be it you know. Cause i have a functionality need to save the form as it is filled and then load it and send it. Any idea how i might be able to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset, just use destroy.

Example: `$( 'input.no_good' ).garlic( 'destroy' );`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 